# Why this function load the server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have this function.

It's a **validation** for register page, need to check if the date is vaild.

I have another function which work well and doesnt run if validation fails.

I thought maybe its in the Validator itself , but as i said, i have another function (and another validator which calls the other function) that work well and I didnt manage to find any diffrences.

CODES:

Failing Function:

```
 function CheckDate(sender, args)
      {

          var DateReg = document.getElementById("DateReg").value;
          DateReg = DateReg.split('/');

          var day = DateReg[0];
          var month = DateReg[1];
          var year = DateReg[2];


          var CurrentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

          args.IsValid = true;  

         if (day < 1 || day > 31 || month < 1 || month > 12 || year > CurrentYear || year < CurrentYear - 120)
          {
             args.IsValid = false; // לא תקין
         }

          return args.IsValid;
      }
```

Failing Validator:

```
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ClientValidationFunction="CheckDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="type age again">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Working Validator:

```
         <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" ClientValidationFunction="CheckInterest" runat="server" ErrorMessage="choose interest">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You're reading a non-existent array `date` and you aren't setting `day` anywhere.

Comment: @ChrisG Edited, look up

Comment: Your valid date is not going to catch invalid dates. "2/31/2018" would be valid by your check....

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok; Got it

the  `getElementById`   did it

Changed it to

```
var DateReg = document.getElementById('<%=DateReg.ClientID %>').value;
```

Seems to work now

Answer (score 0):

Modified version that will validate on a date in the following format "mm/dd/yyyy".

```js
var btnRun = document.getElementById("btnRun");

btnRun.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  CheckDate();
});

function CheckDate(sender, args)
     {
          var isValid = false;
          var DateReg = document.getElementById("DateReg").value;
          var date = new Date(DateReg);
          var cDate = new Date();
          var CurrentYear = cDate.getFullYear();
          isValid = true;
          var iday = date.getDay() + 1;
          var iMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
          var iYear = date.getFullYear();

         if (iday < 1 || iday > 31 || iMonth < 1 || iMonth > 12 || iYear > CurrentYear || iYear < CurrentYear - 120)
          {
              isValid = false;
          }
          console.log(isValid);//just used to show that it works
          return isValid;
      }
```

```html
<input id="DateReg" />
<button id="btnRun">Run</button>
```